# R proper Function for this example

Tags: r

This is my goal below.

```
      x      lx       dx        
 1   15 100000.000 3000.0000 
 2   16  97000.000 2910.0000  
 3   17  94090.000 2822.7000  
 i   xi      lxi      dxi
```

*Formula for each variable*

```
l1 = 100000

lx+1 = lx - dx

dx = lx * deathrate
```

1. First, I bring a table of two columns (1st Col: `age`, 2nd Col: `deathrate`) from a text.

   ```
   deathrate.table <- read.table("deathrate.txt", header = TRUE)

   Age  deathrate 
   1     1   0.00213 
   2     2   0.00096 
   3     3   0.00052
   ```
2. Secondly, in order to calculate **dx based on each age x**, do I have to use `for` loop or other functions?

   In Excel I would use vlookup value of deathrate for each age using 'age' as key in order to calculate "**dx = lx * deathrate**"
3. Lastly, I call for the output to get my goal data.

   ```
   return(data.frame(x=x, lx=lx, dx=dx)
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with a for loop.

```
deathrate.table <- 'Age  deathrate 
1   0.00213 
2   0.00096 
3   0.00052'

deathrate.table <- read.table(text = deathrate.table, header = T)
x <- 1:3
out <- data.frame(x)
out$lx <- 100000
out$deathrate <- deathrate.table$deathrate
out$dx <- out$lx * out$deathrate
for (i in 2:nrow(out)){
  out$lx[i] <- out$lx[i-1] - out$dx[i-1]

}
out$deathrate <- NULL
out
```

Here is the output:

```
  x     lx  dx
1 1 100000 213
2 2  99787  96
3 3  99691  52
```